# Get value depending of current iteration on while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v18, and I want to iterate a `Table Type` using a while loop, so I do:

```
CREATE TYPE [VarcharIdTableType] AS TABLE
(
    [FileName] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Then I use a while loop as:

```
DECLARE @FileTableType [VarcharIdTableType]

INSERT INTO @FileTableType 
VALUES ('test1'),('test2'),('test3')

DECLARE @FileCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @FileTableType), @RowCount INT = 0

WHILE @RowCount <= @FileCount
BEGIN                  
    DECLARE @Content VARCHAR(555)= CONCAT('File name ', @filename)

    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1;
END
```

So I want to get each FileName depending of iteration number, how can I achieve that?

Comment: @DaleK Ohh, in my `@Content` variable inside my while loop, I'm using `@filename` but that's what I want, than variable `@filename` does not exists, so I want to get the filename dpending of each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTANT: Do you actually need a loop? As you haven't shown us what your desired final outcome is we are unable to comment. But in many cases a set based approach will accomplish what you need and if so it should be used.

Making a few assumptions, such as no ID column in your table, and being able to delete rows from your table variable, I would do the following using exists rather than counting rows.

```
DECLARE @FileTableType TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @FileTableType([Name]) VALUES ('test1'), ('test2'), ('test3');

DECLARE @Content VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @Filename VARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @FileTableType)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Filename = [Name] FROM @FileTableType;

    SET @Content = CONCAT('File number ', @Filename);

    DELETE FROM @FileTableType WHERE [Name] = @Filename;
END;
```

However having a known unique identifier on the values in the table variable would be better because if you have duplicate filenames the first code will have issues.

```
DECLARE @FileTableType TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), [Name] VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @FileTableType([Name]) VALUES ('test1'), ('test2'), ('test3');

DECLARE @Content VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @Filename VARCHAR(555), @FileId INT;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @FileTableType)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @FileId = id, @Filename = [Name] FROM @FileTableType;

    SET @Content = CONCAT('File number ', @Filename);

    DELETE FROM @FileTableType WHERE id = @FileId;
END;
```

Note the best practices:

- Terminating all statements with a semi-colon
- Listing all columns when inserting
- Using `VARCHAR(MAX)` for `@Content` since the filename is.

Comment: If you really-really-really need to iterate through the table row-by-row, then a simple cursor is straight-forward and usually most efficient: [Thinking a WHILE loop isn't a CURSOR](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor) , [What impact can different cursor options have?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options) , [The Curse of Cursor Options](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/11/the-curse-of-cursor-options/)

Comment: @VladimirBaranov thats really good information, feel free to leave your own answer, I was just adding the missing link to OPs code, but your suggestions improve it futher.